# How to do some javascript functions after redirecting page to a new url

Tags: javascript, php

```
  header('Location: ../homepage.html');
  echo "<script language='javascript'> console.log('Email already exists'); </script>";
  echo "<script> console.log('ccccc'); </script>";
```

I am just trying to create a registration form. When user tries to register with same Email Id, I want to go back to my html page and open login window[`Trigger login click`].

For initial try, i just try to console some strings after redirecting the page. I don't get those strings.

If i comment out header line, I get those two strings.

How do i solve this issue? Is there any alternative for my scenario?

I have separate html and php files.

EDIT:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)
   {
        //echo "This Email is already used.";
        //Write code to go back to register window
        /*echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                console.log("cdsafcds");
                $(".login_links_login").trigger("click");
                </script>';*/
        $_SESSION['email_exist']="Email Already Exists";
        header('Location: ../homepage.php');
   }
```

homepage.php Part:

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['email_exist']))
 {
   echo "<script language'javascript'>conosle.log('Me');</script>";
 }
 ?>

 <html>
 <head>
 .......
 <form class="right registerForm" id="registerForm" method="POST" action="lib/registration_validate.php">
 ......
```

Comment: That's not possible! you should use a session or cookies before redirection.

Comment: So i must handle errors in the page to which i am redirecting to. Right? Stroe the errors in session variable and process there!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Once you use header - location... your page already starts to load-redirect.. So this is normal behaviour.. You should never have code after/below a header('location')

Comment: It seems that Ajax is your solution. You have to pass form data to php page via an Ajax request and decide if to submit the form or display an error result. All these happen in html page.

Comment: Or send a query string that you can parse on the receiving end either in php or javascript.

Comment: Exactly better way  do not redirect user until form has errors.

Comment: @All, So i must use AJAX. Oops.. Thanks

Comment: You dont have to use ajax, you can have a normal form redirect back to itself and echo the form as normal or with the error/messages. Just ajax these days is a better approach.. But not always for older browsers / support.. So it should still degrade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you use `header('Location: ../homepage.php');` it wont execute the two lines afterward. That is the whole problem. You can do it either by passing variables through header like this : `header('Location: ../homepage.php?log');` or setting session in your php script and use redirect afterwards.

You also need php file in order to catch the parameter you just send and use if like this :

```
if(isset($_GET['log'])){
   echo "<script language='javascript'> console.log('Email already exists'); </script>";
  echo "<script> console.log('ccccc'); </script>";
}
```

or :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['log'])){
       echo "<script language='javascript'> console.log('Email already exists'); </script>";
      echo "<script> console.log('ccccc'); </script>";
    }
```

It depends on what method you used earlier. So turn your homepage.html into homepage.php and put it there.

Comment: Yes I am expecting the last line. I need to turn my html page to php page. Let me try this. Thanks Man

Comment: Ok, let me know if it worked and please check the answer as right if i it helped you :-)

Comment: Sure Man. I do always. But after tried. Because i am new to server side

Comment: Please edit your post with actual content of both files that you are working on. It will be easier for me to see where could be the problem.

Comment: Ok so in order to use $_SESSION you need to start the session first with : 
session_start(); Put this line to the top of the both files.

Comment: Yes. Yes I know that. I started it before if condition in my actual code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75632/discussion-between-redrif-and-gops-ab).